# Css overlay with background color inherited from theme

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put an overlay on my page that will cover all the content.
The problem is that my site allows you to change the theme colors, and the overlay div does not inherit the color from the theme.
The only way to change it is using background-color: rgba( x, y, z, 1.0)

Here is my css for the overlay

```
.bio-overlay {
    position: fixed; /* Sit on top of the page content */
    display: block; 
    width: 100%; /* Full width (cover the whole page) */
    height: 100%; /* Full height (cover the whole page) */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 2048; 
    cursor: pointer; /* Add a pointer on hover */}
```

Is there a way to do this with css? If not I'll settle for some clever javascript. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, if the theme is class-based, you can steal, or even make another class that only has a background color attached to it, and apply it to the overlay as well. This would make it so if the theme changed, the overlay color would change.

```
.backgroundColor {
    background-color: rgba(x, y, z, 1.0);
}
```

---

```
<div class="bio-overlay backgroundColor">
    Content
</div>
```

Another solution is, if the overlay is a child of the theme, you can select the overlay and apply a background color to it that way.

```
.themeClass .bio-overlay {
    background-color: rgba(x, y, z, 1.0);
}
```

This will basically overload the `.bio-overlay` class and if the themeClass is a parent, it'll also apply the background color.

**EDIT**

---

To answer your comment, yes. In the stylesheet YOU edit, do something like this...

```
.whatevertheme .bio-overlay {
    background-color: _whatever_;
}
.whatevertheme2 .bio-overlay {
    background-color: _whatever2_;
}
....
```

It doesn't matter what file the style is in, all that matters is that it is included in the page. As I said in the comment, the only real downside is you'll break theme separation.

Comment: The themes are in a bunch of bootstrap files. (one file per theme). I was trying not to have to modify them and have all my custom css in the site.css file. However, your solution makes sense. I will add the background class to each file and then I'll apply it to my overlay.
Thanks a lot

Comment: If you're trying to avoid editting the bootstrap theme files, you can still put the overlay color in the site.css file. The only downside is you'll be breaking theme separation by including all possible colors in the site.css file.

Comment: like this? 
.background-theme-1 ....
.background-theme-2 ...
...

but then with theme class do I add to the overlay?
or am  I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you'd add individual classes for each theme. I made an edit to the answer to show you what I mean. As for the overlay class, you won't need to create multiple overlay classes if you create it in your `site.css`.